# Two relations to same table with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have the following table:

```
**Project_Survey**
id
survey_id
<many_other_fields>
scheduled_user
completed_by
```

A survey can be scheduled and assigned to a user, but completed by someone else. Both fields are a FK to the table User

Relations in project_survey model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'completed_by');
}

public function scheduledUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'scheduled_user');
}
```

How can I show both users in a table? When I do

```
{{ $survey->firstname }}
```

It returns the firstname of the completed_by user, so how do I get the scheduled user? 
This does not seem to work:

```
{{ $survey->scheduledUser->firstname }}
```

**Update**
I made a mistake here:

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Survey', 'project_survey')
        ->withPivot('id')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'project_survey.completed_by', '=', 'user.id')
        ->select('survey.*', 'project_survey.*', 'user.firstname', 'user.lastname');
}
```

Here I get all the survey that are linked to this project.

**Update 2**

So I changed the relation surveys() to get all the survey of the project with the required data:

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany('App\Project_Survey', 'project_id')
        ->with('survey')
        ->with('scheduledUser')
        ->with('user');
}
```

And if I do a dump of the $survey I get the 3 relations back, so far so good:

```
Project_survey {#961 ▼

#table: "project_survey"
#fillable: array:10 [▶]
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []

#attributes: array:15 [▶]
#original: array:15 [▶]

#relations: array:3 [▼
"survey" => Survey {#1015 ▶}
"scheduledUser" => null
"user" => User {#1111 ▶}
]
```

But I still get an error if I tried to display the data from the relations:

```
  {{ $survey->survey()->number }}
```

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$number

Comment: How do you get the data for your survey? Are you using `->with('scheduledUser');` ?

Comment: Please show results of `dd($survey)`

Comment: {{ $survey->user->firstname }} and {{ $survey->scheduledUser->firstname }}

Comment: see comment below; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264027/two-relations-to-same-table-with-laravel#comment83511084_48264059 I think my relation there is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You should access the relationship to load that particular scheduledUser

```
{{ $survey->scheduledUser()->firstname }}


@foreach($survey as $sur)
  {{ $sur->scheduledUser()->firstName }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried that one also, but it returns; 
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::scheduledUser() `

Comment: okay that happens because $survey its not being pulled from database yet. So show me $suervey      it should be smth $survey->first()->scheduledUser()->firstname in order to work .

Comment: This is on the project page, with a table of all linked surveys. So in the project model i have to following relation to get the surveys:
`public function surveys()
 {
  return $this
   ->belongsToMany('App\Survey', 'project_survey')
   ->withPivot('id')
   ->leftJoin('user', 'project_survey.completed_by', '=', 'user.id')
   ->select('survey.*', 'project_survey.*', 'user.firstname', 'user.lastname');
 } ` and there is my problem. User.firstname.....

Comment: @LazyAdmin it looks like you will have many surveys returned so make sure you itterate them and print the firstname like above

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to use the `->with('<relation>')` to get the related data as suggested by @kerbholz and display the data in the blade template as followed:

`{{ $survey->survey->number }}`